# phantomJS dont work when execute through PHP

Tags: php, phantomjs

i have installed on my server phantomJS (to /usr/bin/phantomjs) when i run it from the shell as root it works perfectly fine, but when i try to run it via PHP it does not work,
those are the commands i have tried:

```
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs --version');
shell_exec('/usr/binphantomjs --version')
exec('phantomjs --version');
shell_exec('phantomjs --version')
```

all of them return empty, 
i have checked that the apache user have access to this folder and even moved it using the php exec function.
i have tried to run it with both system types (i run Linux redhat 64bit)
what else could be my problem ?

Comment: What are the permissions to file: /usr/bin/phantomjs?

Comment: the problem ready was the permissions , i have updated it to 777 and now it works.

Comment: I suggest use https://packagist.org/packages/jakoch/phantomjs-installer to install phantomjs localy with composer